# How to transfer bitcoins from legacy wallet to a descriptor wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core

There is a legacy wallet(probably not be supported in future version of bitcoin core), how can I transfer bitcoins form it to a descriptor wallet?

I know I can just transfer it with transfer fee, I want to know how to put the address from legacy wallet into a brand new descriptor wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can migrate your legacy wallet to a descriptor wallet using the "File > Migrate Wallet" menu on GUI or "migratewallet" RPC

> bitcoin-cli -rpc_wallet="legacy-wallet01" migratewallet

more information can be found at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/managing-wallets.md#migrating-legacy-wallets-to-descriptor-wallets

Comment: So I need open legacy wallet with bitcoin core, execute "migratewallet" in console, wallet will be migrated in site. Is there the same bitcoin in the same address in the new wallet as the legacy one? after migration, the old legacy backup wallet can be opened and own the same fund?

Comment: The RPC will migrate your legacy wallet to a descriptor wallet, in the process a backup to the legacy wallet will be created -.legacy.bak will be created which can be restored using restorewallet RPC

Comment: Check the migratewallet RPC doc for more information

Comment: I want to know whether the btc address and private key change during the migration? And whether both the original legacy wallet and the new descriptor wallet can be used with the same address and the same fund.